# Setting a JLabel visible on JRadioButton click

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I tried setting `JLabel` to being visible only after I select a certain `JRadioButton`. The program is getting an error if I set `lblNewLabel_1.setVisible(true)` in the action performed of a radio button. It worked with the text field, but with this not. What can I do? Is it different with the label? Is there any advice someone can offer me?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Fereastra extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Fereastra frame = new Fereastra();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Fereastra() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 751, 565);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(12, 13, 447, 251);
        contentPane.add(textArea);
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Cautarea pe nivel");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(rdbtnNewRadioButton.isSelected())
                {
                    textField.setVisible(false);
                    textField_1.setVisible(false);
    


                }
                
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton.setBounds(488, 55, 185, 25);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton);       
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_1 = new JRadioButton("Cautarea in adancime");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1.isSelected())
                {
                    textField.setVisible(true);
                    textField_1.setVisible(true);

                }
                else
                {
                    textField.setVisible(false);
                    textField_1.setVisible(false);
            


                }
                
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_1.setBounds(488, 96, 237, 25);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_1);
                    
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_2 = new JRadioButton("Costul uniform");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(rdbtnNewRadioButton_2.isSelected())
                {
                    textField.setVisible(false);
                    textField_1.setVisible(false);

                }
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_2);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_2.setBounds(488, 138, 127, 25);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_2);
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_3 = new JRadioButton("Adancime iterativa");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(rdbtnNewRadioButton_3.isSelected())
                {
                    textField_1.setVisible(true);
                    textField.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    textField_1.setVisible(false);
                    textField.setVisible(false);


                }
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_3);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_3.setBounds(488, 179, 237, 25);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_3);
        
        JRadioButton rdbtnNewRadioButton_4 = new JRadioButton("Greedy");
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(rdbtnNewRadioButton_4.isSelected())
                {
                    textField.setVisible(false);
                    textField_1.setVisible(false);


                }
            }
        });
        buttonGroup.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_4);
        rdbtnNewRadioButton_4.setBounds(488, 221, 127, 25);
        contentPane.add(rdbtnNewRadioButton_4);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Alegeti:");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(488, 13, 84, 33);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(402, 277, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setVisible(false);
        
        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setBounds(246, 277, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(textField_1);
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setVisible(false);

        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Introduceti valorile dorite:");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(22, 277, 212, 21);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);
        lblNewLabel_1.setVisible(false);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to define the JLabel and initialize it with one space.  You would change the text of the JLabel to display or not display, not make the JLabel visible or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your label is declared in function context, put the declaration next the textbox declaration and it should work fine

Comment: I did not manage to do that. I declared JLabel lblNewLabel_1 at the top of the declarations and I still get the error. Can you be more specific please? It would be very helpful. Thank you